# mysql query returns 0 row even though it shows 1 record fround

Tags: php, mysql, join

mysql query return 0 rows, even though it shows 1 record found.
Here is my query:

```
SELECT
  TBCE.TBCE_CourseTitle,
  TBCE.TBCE_CustomizedCourseTitle,
  TBCE.TBCE_Q1,
  TBCE.TBCE_Q2,
  TBCE.TBCE_Q3,
  TBCE.TBCE_Q4,
  TBCE.TBCE_CourseDuration_Days,
  TBCF.TBCF_CoursewareTypeID,
  TBCF.TBCF_CourseLevelID_FK
FROM tbl_epp_bp_site_class_forecast TBCF,
  tbl_epp_bp_site_class_estimation TBCE
WHERE TBCF.TBCF_SiteClassId_PK = TBCE.TBCE_SiteClassId_FK
    AND TBCF.TBCF_BPID_FK = '620'
ORDER BY TBCF.TBCF_CoursewareTypeID ASC
```

There is no record found, but still it shows 1 record found.

Please help me to find out the solution.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you please write the output you get?

Comment: *what* shows "1 record found"? Please provide some code.

Comment: You should update from (deprecated) mysql_* API to PDO or similar

Comment: I have written the query in one function named: getClassDeclarationData(). that function returns me an array of result if data found else return false. 
 $classDeclarationData = $objBusinessPlanMod->getClassDeclarationData($bpId);
    echo count($classDeclarationData);
    
so while i am trying to print count, it shows 1 even though query return 0 rows.

Answer (score 0):

count result for false is one

```
echo count(false);
//output is 1
```

i recommend you to use  mysql_num_rows for this

or use condition before  count that is not false